# Solve T(n)=T(n-1)+2n by backwards iteration method

Tags: algorithm, iteration, recurrence

Can someone help me solve this.
T(1)=5, T(n)=T(n-1)+2n
Explanation of steps would be nice.

Comment: Would you like a slice of toast with the answer to your homework?

Comment: I would like to make it on my own but, my great teacher didn't explained anything.

Comment: @Headzik077: what programming language?

Comment: we using pseudocode in the classes i need to do : designate the class of complexity for : T(1)=5, T(n)=T(n-1)+2n by using backwards iterating method

Comment: To make it on your own: starting from the known T(1), deduce T(2) using the recurrence formula. Then T(3), T(4)... Be sure to avoid executing the additions, so as to let a pattern emerge.

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=T(1)%3D5,+T(n)%3DT(n-1)%2B2n

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Iterative approach

You can solve this by a simple iteration (Java):

```
public static int T (int n) {
    if(n <= 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("n must be larger or equal to one.");
    }
    int result = 5;
    for(int i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
        result = result + 2*i;
    }
    return result;
}
```

[**jDoodle**](http://jdoodle.com/a/UW)

The program works as follows: first we perform a bounds check: if the *n* is less than or equal to zero, the result is undefined. Next we assign `5` to the `result`. Now before we enter the `for` loop, `result` is equal to *T(n)*, next for each iteration in the `for` loop, we calculate *T(i)* based on *T(i-1)* (which is equal to `result` at that point in time). Since the `for` loop does iterations up to (and including) *n*, at the end of the iteration `result` is equal to *T(n)*.

## Constant-time approach

Based on the iterative case, we can simplify this somation [using WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=5%2Bsum+of+2*i+with+i+from+2+to+n):

[image: 5+sum of 2*i with i from 2 to n is equal to n square plus n plus 3]

We can thus simplify our program such that it runs in constant time:

```
public static int T (int n) {
    if(n <= 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("n must be larger or equal to one.");
    }
    return n*n+n+3;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To compute each next value of T you have to know a previous one. That is what "iterative" means. You have to go through a loop, at each step of which you compute T(n), starting from T(2), T(3),... etc. till you reach some destination element. The variable T is supposed to be an array.

Comment: What about this? is this possible to do it like this ?       T(n) = T(n-1) + 2n

T(n-1) =T(n-2) + 2n-1

T(n-2) = T(n-3) + 2n-2

Comment: T(1)=5, T(2)=T(1)+2, T(3)=T(2)+4, T(4)=T(3)+6, ... till you reach some number n which is declared to be the final one

Comment: And if i would like to get class of complexity (idk if i can translate it like this from my language). How can i do this?

Comment: the complexity is O(n), linear time, but do you need to use a recursion in this problem? because for me, a recursion is not an iteration

Comment: the task is : designate the class of complexity for : T(1)=5, T(n)=T(n-1)+2n by using backwards iterating method